# Alt key necessary to shortcuts on third party applications

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

Hi I am using intellij with the macOS keymap but according to the key map reference for example with F6 move or Shift + f6 will rename, but why I need to press the alt key? there is a way a can use inside intellij as the reference state? without the alt? because apparently there is a overlapping between the OS and the intellij key mapping, because when I press F6 will increase the light of the laptop for example

Comment: What OS and keyboard are you using? I have not found such conflicts reported by Mac users in my team.

Comment: macOS Catalina version 10.15.3

Comment: And I am using US keyboard on the Mac and the macOS keymap inside intellij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of the function keys is governed by System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard tab > Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys. Enable that if you want to use e.g. F6 without having to press Alt/Option.